# call function within ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call a function from within an AJAX success handler, but it is being ignored

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../ajax/create_audit_standard_carosel.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: 'audit_id='+audit_id+'&user_id='+user_id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        $('#num').html(response.standards_count);
        $('#standards_list').html(response.output);
            jQuery(function($) {
                $("#selected_standards").touchCarousel({
                   itemsPerPage: 4,             
                   scrollbar: true,
                   scrollbarAutoHide: true,
                   scrollbarTheme: "dark",              
                   pagingNav: false,
                   snapToItems: true,
                   scrollToLast: true,
                   useWebkit3d: true,               
                   loopItems: false         
                });
            });
     }, // End of success function of ajax form
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      alert(thrownError);
    }
}); // End of ajax call
```

The responses are correct and the contents of `#standards_list` are amended with the correct content so I know that the AJAX call is working correctly, but the function within the success call is completely ignored.

Comment: exactly what is completly ignored? Have you done any console.log ?

Comment: images are uploaded to the server which are displayed in a list and the layout is styled by the carousel function.  The images are uploaded ok, are displayed in a list but because the carousel function doesn't load the carousel isn't styled correctly.  If I manually refresh the page the carousel function loads because it is also on the page

Comment: Why `jQuery(function($) {` …?

Comment: @CBroe because I'm still learning and it seems that is the bit I got wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the function beginning directly after where you update the `#standards_list` element, it's because you are trying to bind to an event that has long since fired.

Passing a function to the global jQuery function is a shortcut for binding to the `document.ready` event. This event is fired when the page loaded and will not fire again as a result of the AJAX call.

Just remove the wrapping function and call the `touchCarousel` method after updating the `#standards_list element`, e.g:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../ajax/create_audit_standard_carosel.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: 'audit_id='+audit_id+'&user_id='+user_id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        $('#num').html(response.standards_count);
        $('#standards_list').html(response.output);
        $("#selected_standards").touchCarousel({
            itemsPerPage: 4,             
            scrollbar: true,
            scrollbarAutoHide: true,
            scrollbarTheme: "dark",              
            pagingNav: false,
            snapToItems: true,
            scrollToLast: true,
            useWebkit3d: true,               
            loopItems: false         
        });
    }, // End of success function of ajax form
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
    }
}); // End of ajax call`
```

Comment: Your explanation is NOT correct here.  If you call jQuery's `.ready()` after it has fired, it will just call your callback right away.  It will call it.  That said, there is no reason to wrap this code in jQuery's ready logic at all because the document is already loaded - though I don't see how that actually causes the OP's issue.

Comment: Usually yes, binding to the ready event after the event has fired will trigger the bound function to be invoked immediately, but there must be something in how the AJAX response or event is handled that is preventing it